# Issue with PHP if/else values

Tags: php, if-statement

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$device_id =$obj['device_id'];
$num =$obj['sensor_value'];
$sensor_value =(int)$num;


if ($sensor_value > 100){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rr_emergency (device_id,sensor_value) VALUES('$device_id','$sensor_value');";
    $result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
else {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO general_logging (device_id,sensor_value) VALUES('$device_id','$sensor_value');";
    $result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

The `else` statement works fine. However, when `$sensor_value` is greater than 100, the `if` part of my statement never fires. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check for errors... It probably enters the `if` but something goes wrong.

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, thanks,...I know that. Only testing some things. I'll do the proper PDO syntax later.

Comment: @FirstOne The PHP is being "fired" by a third party web service, so I'm not sure how view an echo if I put one in there...that is...where would it ```echo``` to?

Comment: That's tricky. Can't you run some simulation tests (do the request yourself) to see it? Recheck the code: does `rr_emergency` table exist? Does it have those columns? Could it be that any 'requirement' from the table is not being met? Can you check if those variables have the values you'd expect them to have (or any value at all)?

Comment: @FirstOne I flipped around the tables in my code (which one gets sent data based on the if/else) and I'm able to INSERT fine into both. The condition of ">100" never seems to be reached though. In both cases, I'm able to insert the sensor_value (as an INT) when the value is less than 100. When it is above 100, no insert is made to either table.

Comment: How are you sure that your `if (true)` clause never fires? Have you tried replacing `$sensor_value > 100` with `true`, or logging/echoing a message BEFORE you run the db query? Anything in your log file regarding errors?

Comment: @NathanielFord how do I do this: "Have you tried replacing ```$sensor_value > 100``` with ```true```"

Comment: @jonmrich Literally replace that line with `if (TRUE) {` That should evaluate to the execution of your first clause. But you should still echo or log something, to show that you're in the clause and rule out a sql issue.

Comment: @NathanielFord What's really weird is that if I change it to if ```($sensor_value >1)``` then the IF fires just fine and inserts into the DB and doing ```if(TRUE)``` also works

Comment: How do you know it's? When you changed to `>1`, did it insert a value greater than `100` in the database?

Comment: @RyanVincent Where do I view this ```var_dump``` results since I'm not executing the PHP...a third party web service is.

Comment: @FirstOne I can see the value real-time in the webservice and see the data it is sending. When I changed to ```>1``` it inserted the actual value from the web service (e.g., 3)

Comment: "Only testing some things. I'll do the proper PDO syntax later." And that's how code like this accidentally makes it into production. Testing/practicing bad habits cements bad habits.

Comment: For anybody wondering, here is [the catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340838/issue-with-php-if-else-values#comment64096565_38340977)

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely that `if/else` as a language construct is randomly broken. However, you can do some things to determine if you're doing what you think you are:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$device_id =$obj['device_id'];
$num =$obj['sensor_value'];
$sensor_value =(int)$num;

echo "num=$num\n"; //Are you actually getting a value from $obj?
echo "sensor_value=$sensor_value\n"; //Compare to num. Is it being cast correctly?

if ($sensor_value > 100){
    echo "Inside 'True' clause\n";
    try {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO rr_emergency (device_id,sensor_value) VALUES('$device_id','$sensor_value');";
      $result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Caught exception trying to execute sql: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
else {
  ...
}
```

By doing these things we confirm that everything is operating *as you expect*. Chances are this will reveal the problem.

**A Note On Casting**

To cast from a string to an integer, you should use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$sensor_value = intval($num);
```

Comment: Where can I actually view the results of these ```echo``` since I'm not executing the PHP myself? A webservice is just making a POST to it.

Comment: I'm definitely getting a value correctly. As long as the value of ```$sensor_value``` isn't greater than 100 (i.e., satisfying the iF condition), the correct value is inserted in the database per the instructions in my ELSE

Comment: @jonmrich Does the webservice provide logging? In that case you can use that logger instead of echo. It might show up if you 'view source' on the html, but I would need more details about the infrastructure to know.

Comment: @jonmrich You are getting *a* value, but are you sure that value is an integer?

Comment: I'm thinking the issue is whether or not it's an integer. Let's try that...the webservice will return a whole number between 0 and probably 1000 max. What should my type be in the DB and what should I cast in PHP?

Comment: The database should have type information in it telling you what the `sensor_value` field should be.

Comment: I know...I can change it to whatever makes sense. It was INT (10)...I've tried as FLOAT (6,2) and cast as a float, but nothing is working.

Comment: @jonmrich I have to reiterate how important it is to 'probe' the values the code thinks it has. Remember you could run this locally, using the input json file you have and skipping the database part. You should also look into how this webservice handles exceptions and logging, and leverage that to see what is up.

Comment: Hey there...thanks for the suggestions...hugely dumb mistake on my part. I had the webservice set to only send an HTTP request when the value was under 100, so it never called my PHP when it was above that value. Your reiteration forced me to to do the hard work. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! Having a reliable feedback loop is key to engineering.